# When exactly do I set an ownerReference's controller field to true?

Tags: kubernetes

I am writing a Kubernetes controller.

Someone creates a custom resource via `kubectl apply -f custom-resource.yaml`.  My controller notices the creation, and then creates a `Deployment` that pertains to the custom resource in some way.

I am looking for the proper way to set up the `Deployment`'s `ownerReferences` field such that a deletion of the custom resource will result in a deletion of the `Deployment`.  I understand I can do this like so:

```
ownerReferences:
- kind: <kind from custom resource>
  apiVersion: <apiVersion from custom resource>
  uid: <uid from custom resource>
  controller: <???>
```

I'm unclear on whether this is case where I would set `controller` to `true`.

The Kubernetes reference documentation says (in its entirety):

> If true, this reference points to the managing controller.

Given that a controller is running code, and an owner reference actually references another Kubernetes resource via matching `uid`, `name`, `kind` and `apiVersion` fields, this statement is nonsensical: a Kubernetes object reference can't "point to" code.

I have a sense that the documentation author is trying to indicate that—using my example—because the user didn't directly create the `Deployment` herself, it should be marked with some kind of flag indicating that a controller created it instead.

Is that correct?

The follow on question here is of course: OK, what behavior changes if `controller` is set to `false` here, but the other `ownerReference` fields are set as above?

Comment: Am I understand you correctly? You want to create a custom controller, which will work like this. When someone creates, for example, a Pod, you want to create a Deployment which will control this Pod?

Comment: Not exactly.  I am creating a custom controller that works like this: when someone creates, for example, a `Foo`, I want my custom controller to create a `Deployment`.  When creating this `Deployment`, should my custom controller arrange for `controller: true` to be present in the `Deployment`'s `metadata` or not?  Why or why not?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`ownerReferences` has two purposes:

- **Garbage collection**: Refer to the answer of [ymmt2005](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61673465/1863595). Essentially all owners are considered for GC. Contrary to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51176204/1863595) the `controller` field has no impact on GC.
- **Adoption**: The `controller` field prevents fighting over resources which are to be adopted. Consider a replica set. Usually, the replica set controller creates the pods. However, if there is a pod which matches the label selector it will be adopted by the replica set. To prevent two replica sets fighting over the same pod, the latter is given a unique controller by setting the `controller` to `true`. If a resource already has a controller it will not be adopted by another controller. Details are in the [design proposal](https://github.com/kubernetes/design-proposals-archive/blob/acc25e14ca83dfda4f66d8cb1f1b491f26e78ffe/api-machinery/controller-ref.md).

**TLDR**: The field `controller` is only used for adoption and not GC.

Comment: Interesting. Should this attribute have therefore been named `controlled`?  As in, "I am already controlled, don't try to control/adopt me"?

Comment: `controller` is not a property of the object itself but of the owner reference. It tells you whether *this* owner is also the controller of the object.

Comment: @fischerman Just to confirm my understanding, this means the ONLY ONE owner reference object should have `controller: true` and all others should have `controller: false`. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. `[...]. If this object is managed by a controller, then an entry in this list will point to this controller, with the controller field set to true. There cannot be more than one managing controller.` from https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.22/#objectmeta-v1-meta

Comment: Can't edit this answer right now (edit queue woes?) but this is a working (and hopefully permanent) link to the [design proposal](https://github.com/kubernetes/design-proposals-archive/blob/acc25e14ca83dfda4f66d8cb1f1b491f26e78ffe/api-machinery/controller-ref.md)

Answer (score 4):

According to the source code of Kubernetes, the object will be garbage collected only after *all* objects in `ownerReferences` field are deleted.

https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/15d95c0b2af3f4fcf46dce24105e5fbb9379af5a/pkg/apis/meta/v1/types.go#L240-L247

```
// List of objects depended by this object. If ALL objects in the list have
// been deleted, this object will be garbage collected. If this object is managed by a controller,
// then an entry in this list will point to this controller, with the controller field set to true.
// There cannot be more than one managing controller.
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation:

> Sometimes, Kubernetes sets the value of ownerReference automatically. For example, when you create a ReplicaSet, Kubernetes automatically sets the ownerReference field of each Pod in the ReplicaSet. In 1.6, Kubernetes automatically sets the value of ownerReference for objects created or adopted by ReplicationController, ReplicaSet, StatefulSet, DaemonSet, and Deployment.
>
> You can also specify relationships between owners and dependents by manually setting the `ownerReference` field.

Basically, a Deployment is on the top of the ownership hierarchy, and `ownerReference` is not set to it automatically. Therefore, you can manually add `ownerReference` to your Deployment to create the reference to your `Foo` resource.

You asked:

> The follow on question here is of course: OK, what behavior changes if `controller` is set to `false` here, but the other `ownerReference` fields are set as above?

OwnerReference is used by a Garbage Collector. The role of the Kubernetes Garbage Collector is to delete certain objects that once had an owner, but no longer have it.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/21de1bffe600f61f4873ae774a60f7a7d37ac9bf/pkg/apis/meta/v1/types.go#L273-L275) to the description of the OwnerReference structure on Github. As you mentioned, if `controller: true`, the reference points to the managing controller, in other words, the owner. And also, it is the instruction for Garbage Collector's behavior related to the object and its owner. If `controller: false`, Garbage Collector manages the object as an object without an owner, for example, allows to delete it freely.

For more information, you can visit the following links:
- [Garbage Collection](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/)
- [Deletion and Garbage Collection of Kubernetes Objects](https://thenewstack.io/deletion-garbage-collection-kubernetes-objects/)

Comment: You write: "If `controller: false`, Garbage Collector manages the object as an object without an owner, for example, allows to delete it freely."  But `controller` is a field in an `ownerReference` `struct`.  What does it mean to have an `ownerReference` with `controller: false`?  If `controller: false` effectively nullifies the owner reference, then why not simply express the same intent by simply not having an owner reference to begin with?

Comment: @LairdNelson, if `controller: false` and other fields in `ownerReference` are filled, they are ignored. Usually, Kubernetes fills these fields automatically. Therefore, if you want to add an owner manually, you need to add `ownerReference` with `controller: true`, if you don't want to add an owner, you can just skip adding `ownerReference` or add it with `controller: false`

Comment: Thanks very much; what a strange, verbose collection of fields.  So I understand now that the whole stanza's presence is what designates ownership, and that the presence of `controller : true` within it is superfluous and unnecessarily verbose.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. The whole GC documentation always talks about `ownerReferences` but never mentions that the `controller` field needs to be set to `true`, the only time this field appears in the whole documentation for the GC provided in the answer is in an example that happens to have it set to true, but it never mentions that it is a requirement for GC to work.

Comment: No documentation mentions this field, it's just set to true in all examples. Please link to a source that supports your claim for the significance of the `controller` field, because I can't find anything besides this question.

Comment: According to the implementation of [k8s garbage collector](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/67a7509ef30ad5bdd41fdf0e050e9fc625e1e951/pkg/controller/garbagecollector/garbagecollector.go#L453), only after all objects in ownerReferences field are deleted, the object will be garbage collected.  And `Controller field` is set if you your `controller implementation` (The official controllers, say replicaSet etc relies on this field) relies on this field.

Comment: I've created a corrected answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65825463/1863595